# Show that solutions of second order ODE have infinitely many zeros

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let a solution of a homogeneous second order linear ODE with constant coefficients be given and let it be non-zero. I want to show that it follows from this that every solution of this ODE has infinitely many zeros.

The given ODE is of the form

$y''(t)+by'(t)+cy(t)=0, \quad b,c\in\mathbb{R}$

**Case 1**: The discriminant is greater than zero, hence we get two different real solutions of the associated polynomial and the solutions of the ODE are:
$y(t)=c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_2e^{\lambda_2 t}$ 
with real constants $c_1, c_2$. This solution does not have infinitely many roots, regardless of the eigenvalues.

**Case 2**: The discriminant is equal zero, hence we get as solution
$y(t)=c_1e^{\lambda t} +c_2 te^{\lambda t}$ which also does not have infinitely many zeros.

The only **remaining case** is where the eigenvalues are complex. We then get solutions of the form
$y(t)=c_1e^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t)+c_2e^{\alpha t}\sin(\beta t)$ where $\lambda = \alpha\pm i\beta$

It has to hold that the eigenvalues are purely complex, so that we have

$y(t)=c_1\cos(\beta t) +c_2\sin(\beta t)$

This must then be the general form of the solution, where not both $c_1, c_2$ can be zero by assumption.

Is my reasoning correct? Did I miss anything? I would appreciate any improvements in my argumentation if it should be correct. (e.g. I did not prove that the first two cases have only finitely many roots)

Comment: The Storm-Picone comparison theorem tells you that if one solution has infinitely many solutions, then any other solution does too. This applies also for non-constant coefficients.

Comment: I don't know this theorem, the problem should be solvable with only the knowledge of the solutions. But thank you for sharing this interesting theorem.

Comment: For constant coefficients you have discussed all the cases and should thus have proven the claim. However, the claim seems incomplete, what is the property of the given solution that excludes the first two cases?

Comment: @Lutzl not all the cases, $b,c=0$ is not excluded so $y''=0$ a polynomial of second degree is not excluded. It doesn't have infinitely many zero either.

Comment: @zwim: This falls under case 2, a double root $λ=0$. And the solution is a linear function, a quadratic term would require a non-zero right side.

Comment: @LutzL The property which excludes the first one would be that the eigenvalues are not complex. I basically showed that for a solution to exist with inf. many zeros, the associated polynomials must have complex eigenvalues. I understand by a particular solutions, solutions with particular constants, so if one solution has just the constants determined, I can infer from it the general form.

Comment: That is not what the first two sentences say. Make sure that your solution, which in itself is consistent, matches the actual task. The task says *"Given this ODE form and a solution with [properties not listed], any other solution has infinitely many zeros"*. In the current form this statement is wrong, as the first two cases have only finitely many solutions. You solved the different task *"Give conditions on $b,c$ so that non-zero solutions have infinitely many zeros."*